# Weird constructors behavior

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {
        cout << 0;
    }
    Foo(Foo &f)
    {
        cout << 1;
    }
};

void someFunction(Foo f) {};

int main()
{
    Foo f1;           //displays 0 (as expected)
    Foo f2(f1);       //displays 1 (as expected)
    someFunction(f1); //displays 1 (why?)
    someFunction(f2); //displays 1 (why?)

    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why function 'someFunction' calls second constructor. I thought it will just call first constructor, with no parameters, and displays 0.

Maybe I am missing something obvious...

Comment: `someFunction` takes a copy of it's parameter.  `Foo(Foo &f)` can be used as a copy constructor. `Foo(Foo const &f)` would be a better copy constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second constructor is a *copy* constructor, and when you pass an argument to a function by value it is *copied*, which invokes the copy constructor.

The first constructor (the *default* constructor) is only called when creating an object from scratch, and without any arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you call *someFunction*, the compiler invokes the copy-constructor to copy the object `f1` or `f2` into `f`.

To avoid that, just declare the function with a reference parameter to a *Foo* object, like so:

```
int someFunction(Foo &f) {}
```

Then call it as usual:

```
someFunction(f1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It will never call default constructor because you are just copying foo object. It will use copy constructor and if there is no copy contructor available, it is using the second which is similar to that.